# Reducing the APK size - Building so files for only certain platforms

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I am trying to reduce my Android app. It has a differenct packages, a client package which depenend of bunch of other packages. I am analyzing the APK and saw there are so files for different paltforms namely x86 and armeabi-v7a. I dont want x86 currently. I am using splits to restrict the so files for x86 platform with following code in my build.gradle file.

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable false

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.

            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "armeabi-v7a"

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

But still I could see the x86 files. Can someone help me in what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why dont you use android app-bundle[https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle]?

Comment: how about using proguard ?

Comment: Thanks @Ezio for sharing your thoughts. I  am using progurard to exclude some classes that I am not using. But not sure if I can restruct platform specifically. Say I am using a package. can I restrict this package not to build and generate so for x86 platform alone with proguard?

Answer (score 0):

Use `abiFilters` from [NdkOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html) to include the native libraries only of certain ABIs.

Example:

```
android {
    // Similar to other properties in the defaultConfig block, you can override
    // these properties for each product flavor in your build configuration.
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            // Tells Gradle to build outputs for the following ABIs and package
            // them into your APK.
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
}
```